# Can't figure out whats causing this display bug in IE, Android and IOS

Tags: android, html, css, ios, mobile

So first things first the only reason I include IE in this is its the only browser that i can get to render the issue. My thought process was that if I can fix the display issue in IE it would resolve itself on the mobile devices.

The issue is that the radio buttons need to be aligned to the left. The headache i'm facing is that i have to make this work with CSS because I do not have the ability to change the HTML structure of the code, since i am optimizing this for mobile, any changes to the HTML would affect hundreds of other pages, thus I've been told not to change the HTML structure of the page. Which sort of throws semantics out the window. If someone could help me to understand what exactly is happening with this code, it displays correctly on most desktop browsers, but not IE, Android or iOS.

[image: Issue]

The only CSS affecting the inputs and spans is here:

```
.mobile .formBound span {
  display: block;
 }

.mobile form span, .mobile form input {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile .formBound input {
  float: left;
}
```

This is the HTML structure of the elements:

```
<div class="g3 group_3" id="tabindex_11">
    <div style="width:inherit;">
        <span class="field_label" id="field_label_donateCharity">How much would you normally be willing to donate to charity every year?:</span>
        <span class="requiredField">*</span>
    </div>
    <input type="radio"  name="donateCharity" id="donateCharity" class="offerRadioButton {required:true}" value="Less than $10">
    <span class="radioCaption">Less than $10</span>
    <input type="radio"  name="donateCharity" id="donateCharity" class="offerRadioButton {required:true}" value="$10-$100">
    <span class="radioCaption">$10-$100</span>
    <input type="radio"  name="donateCharity" id="donateCharity" class="offerRadioButton {required:true}" value="$101-$200">
    <span class="radioCaption">$101-$200</span>
    <input type="radio"  name="donateCharity" id="donateCharity" class="offerRadioButton {required:true}" value="$201-$500">
    <span class="radioCaption">$201-$500</span>
    <input type="radio"  name="donateCharity" id="donateCharity" class="offerRadioButton {required:true}" value="$501 or more">
    <span class="radioCaption">$501 or more</span>
</div>
```

I'm fairly certain at this point that the issue is something to do with the HTML structure of the code.

Any suggestions as to what could be done to get this to display properly on a mobile device?

Comment: Not the problem, but IDs must be unique within a page, and you've reused `donateCharity` on every single radio button

Comment: Yes that I know, like i said semantics are kinda out the window, i wish i could edit the HTML but i don't have the option to do that currently, unless i can show that is definitively the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here ended up being a small script that would find the elements and set a 
 tag after each element

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by this style:

```
.mobile .formBound input {
  float: left;
}
```

This will be tricky to fix, since you can't modify the markup. I would suggest experimenting with ":after" pseudo selectors to clear float. Something like this:

```
span.radioCaption:after {
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
}
```

It would be helpful if you included a JSFiddle that reproduces your problem in IE.

Comment: Let me try this and then i'll see if  can get a working fiddle running

Comment: Clear both appears to drop the span below the input

Comment: There is definitely something else that's messing with it. Here's my JSFiddle with :after - http://jsfiddle.net/dEvqu/

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing more of the structure / CSS rules.  Have you tried adding !important to your input float rules?